# Is it possible to edit an app.config file from inside an executable?

Tags: c#, .net

The App.config is inside the executable and I no longer have the source code for the application.

Is it possible in anyway to extract the App.config from the executable, edit it and then pack it inside the executable again?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing a C# resource file of a compiled assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006387/editing-a-c-sharp-resource-file-of-a-compiled-assembly)

Comment: What do you mean by "inside the executable"? App.config files normally live alongside it on disk.